# rm does not delete files piped from ls within a script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have some kind of unusual situation where the rm command does not work when passing the list of files through pipe

If I do the following on the shell directly it works just fine

```
filepath="testdata/copy"
filename="copy20210902.txt"

ls -td ${filepath}/${filename:0:4}* |awk 'NR>5' # just for testing
rm -f `ls -td ${filepath}/${filename:0:4}* |awk 'NR>5'`
```

the list in the code sample shows me the older than the last 5 and the following line deletes said files as expected.

Now, I have a function (Delete_Older_Files) within a script that "theoretically" should do the same

```
#!/bin/ksh

# function to get the file path from the argument passed when running the script
function Get_Path #args: <path>
{
    CONF_FILE_PATH=${1}
}

# function that searches for all conf files
# and executes the transfer flow with those parameters
function Read_All_Config_Files #args: <conf_file_path>
{
  for f in ${1}/*.conf; do
    pipe_config=`sed -n 1p ${f}` #reads the contents of the config file and stores it on pipe_config
    Parse_Config_Content ${pipe_config}
    Delete_Older_Files ${filepath} ${filename}
  done
}

# function that parses the contents of the config files
function Parse_Config_Content #args: <conf_to_parse>
{
  parsed_conf_array=""
  filepath=""
  filename=""

  IFS='|' # | (pipe) is set as delimiter
  read -rA parsed_conf_array <<< "${1}"   # parses the config string separated by |(pipe)
  IFS=' ' # change delimiter to the default

  filepath=${parsed_conf_array[5]}
  filename=${parsed_conf_array[7]}
}

#
function Delete_Older_Files #args: <filepath> <filename>
{
  ls -td ${1}/${2:0:4}* |awk 'NR>5' # just for testing
  rm -f `ls -td ${1}/${2:0:4}* |awk 'NR>5'`
  rm -f `ls -td testdata/copy/copy*` # just for testing
  :
}

# Main 
CONF_FILE_PATH=""

if [ ${#} -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "The script takes a single parameter and you passed ${#} parameters"
  exit 2
fi

Get_Path $1
Read_All_Config_Files ${CONF_FILE_PATH}
```

When I call the script, the list of files works just fine but the 'problem' comes with the delete part, it does nothing and I'm out of ideas.

I have even added `` rm -f `ls -td testdata/copy/copy* `` to the script just to test if it was the *awk* causing the issue but still it does not delete anything

Here is a sample of the config file that gets parsed

`copy_test|copy_test|copy_test|copy_test|copy_test|testdata/copy|copy_test|copy20210928.txt|copy_test|copy_test`

please advise

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Using `ls` in this way is an antipattern: It introduces bugs, and there's no advantage it offers to counteract / justify those bugs.

Comment: With respect to sorting by time, [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) covers best practices for doing so (which don't involve `ls -t`).

Comment: Beyond that, consider running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/, and reading the wiki pages associated with bugs it flags.